# Redundant DB column for indexing

Tags: database, database-design

I'm defining a few database tables, roughly looking like this:

[image: DB]

In order to quickly run a query where a `Person`'s `MailMessages` are retrieved in time order, regardless of what `MailAccount` they were sent to, I want an index for the MailMessage table, sorted by (PersonId, ReceivedTime). That means adding a redundant PersonId column to the MailMessage table, like this:

[image: DB]

...or does it? Is there any neater way of doing this? If not, is the best practice to make PersonId a foreign key in the MailMessage table, or should this not be done, as it's conceptually not a foreign key but rather just a column used for the (PersonId, ReceivedTime) index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could do that, but it would require having a key in table `MailAccount` on `{MailAccountId, PersonId}`, so it can be referenced by the FK in table `MailMessage`. From the perspective of enforcing uniqueness, this is redundant, since `{MailAccountId}` alone is already unique.

There is an alternative: use identifying relationships and natural keys. For example:

[image]

This achieves essentially the same goal, but with just one key (and the underlying index) per table.

Note the order of PK fields in the bottom table: it allows a query...

```
SELECT *
FROM MailMessage
WHERE PersonId = ?
ORDER BY ReceivedTime
```

...to be satisfied by an index range scan on the primary index. And if the table happens to be [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), the DBMS won't even have to access the table heap after that (there is no table heap at all - rows are stored directly in the B-Tree).

Avoidance of JOINs without resorting to redundant keys (which is also good for clustering) is one of the pros of natural keys versus surrogate keys. As you can imagine, the [list of pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) does not end there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is called [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).  A full discussion of the pros and cons of this concept are a bit much for SO.

This type of optimization is also possible using a [Materialized View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) (called an Indexed View in SQL Server).

Comment: +1: Having a name for it (denormalization) makes it feel so much more legitimate :-).